# Calcular parámetros una Distribución de Weibull - Python

Tags: python

Buen día

Estoy teniendo problemas para implementar la biblioteca `scipy.stats.exponweib` que se ecncuentra en: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponweib.html#scipy.stats.exponweib

**EXPLICACIÓN E INFORMACIÓN DEL ASUNTO**

**1. DataSet**

Tengo un DataFrame con información de datas y velocidad, con una estructura igual a la tabla que muestro a continuación, lo cual lo llamaré `df_wind`

```js
       data                         vel
0   2010-01-01 00:10:00 12.49
1   2010-01-01 00:20:00 14.06
2   2010-01-01 00:30:00 14.07
3   2010-01-01 00:40:00 13.06
4   2010-01-01 00:50:00 12.50
```

El DataFrame completo se encuentra en: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/6k00/data_base_eolica/main/database_eolica.csv

**2. Parametros que debo determinar**

Considerando que la definición de densidad de probabilidad de Weibull, es definida como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este contexto debo determinar los valores de **c** y **k** y graficar el histograma de distribución de Weibull

Donde:
`c`= Parametro de escala
y
`k` = Parametro de forma

**3. Biblioteca**

Por el momento, estoy aplicando el siguiente codigo para el calculo de `c` y `k`

```js
wind = df_wind['vel']

(loc, scale) = s.exponweib.fit_loc_scale(wind, 1, 1)
print('El factor de forma es:',loc, 'El factor de escala es:', scale)
```

Lo cual obtengo resultados, pero no estoy entendiendo si está calculando lo que realmente necesito, o sea el valor correcto de `c` y `k`

**PROBLEMA**

Por lo tanto, la dificultad que estoy teniendo es:

1. Como implementar correctamente la biblioteca `scipy.stats.exponweib` para resolver el asunto mencionado
2. Como generar un histograma de distribución de Weibull de mi database

Desde ya agradezco su tiempo de leer esta pregunta